# How to break away from a transaction loop in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this controller code where I want to break away from the loop when there is an error in one of methods it has . Below is the example

```
def batch_save
  # some code

  SheetEntry.transaction do
    params[:entries].keys.each do |key|
      method1(key,value)
      method2(key,value)
    end         
  end
rescue SheetEntriesInvalid => e
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {
      flash[:error] = "Sorry, cannot save "
      redirect_to :action => :index
    }
    format.js { render :batch_save }
  end
end

def method1(key,value)
  if period_opened(value) == false
    flash[:error]=" Please contact Administrator."
    redirect_to :action => :index 
  end
end
```

I want to know how to break away from the transaction loop when there is an error in `method1` and just redirect to index and show the error in `method1`.

Comment: is raising `SheetEntriesInvalid` not working? I would just create another error (`PeriodOpenedException` or something) and throw/catch that just like [it appears] you're doing with `SheetEntriesInvalid`, you should be able to set the `flash` in `method1` if you need to customize the error based on where it's thrown and then throw the error and redirect in `batch_save`

Comment: raise SheetEntriesInavlid is not working... Can some one show me an example of how to do this?